# Creating a new column of consecutive token (like n-gram) in R

Tags: r, n-gram

I have this dataset;

```
A        B
URBAN    1
PLAN     2
```

I wish that new column is added like this;

```
A        A`      B
URBAN    URB     1
URBAN    RBA     1
URBAN    BAN     1
PLAN     PLA     2
PLAN     LAN     2
```

How do I make the A' column in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat=read.table(text="A        B
URBAN    1
PLAN     2",h=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

 library(zoo)
 d=lapply(dat$A,function(y)
 rollapply(1:nchar(y),3,function(x)substr(y,min(x),max(x))))
 data.frame(dat[rep(dat$B,lengths(d)),],A1=unlist(d),row.names = NULL)
      A B unlist.d.
1 URBAN 1       URB
2 URBAN 1       RBA
3 URBAN 1       BAN
4  PLAN 2       PLA
5  PLAN 2       LAN
```

Comment: Combing your idea and mine, one approach would be the following. `dat %>% mutate(whatever = lapply(A,function(y) rollapply(1:nchar(y), width = 3, function(x) substr(y, min(x), max(x))))) %>% unnest(whatever)`. This let us type less.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way. I am sure there are much more concise way to handle this job. But I think the following will do. For each row in `mydf`, I applied `substr()` to create three-letter elements. The `Map()` part is producing the elements. Since there are some non-desired elements, I further subsetted them with another `lapply()`. Finally, `unnest()` splits elements in each list and create a long-format data.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>%
mutate(whatever = lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(x) {
                     unlist(Map(function(j, k) substr(mydf$A[x], start = j, stop = k),
                             1:nchar(mydf$A[x]), 3:nchar(mydf$A[x])))
                     }) %>%
                  lapply(function(x) x[nchar(x) ==3])) %>%
unnest(whatever)

      A B whatever
1 URBAN 1      URB
2 URBAN 1      RBA
3 URBAN 1      BAN
4  PLAN 2      PLA
5  PLAN 2      LAN
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(A = c("URBAN", "PLAN"), B = 1:2), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @akrun I see. If we use `map()` or `Map()`, `unnest()` is a good friend in this kind of operation. I am reading your code now. Can you explain the regex? I still have lots to learn in this area.

Comment: The regex is a positive lookahead.  By itself, it is non-capturing, but it can be captured by wrapping with parentheses (`(...)`)

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the information. I like the idea of using `str_match_all()`. This makes the job really easy.

Comment: @akrun I have a question. In your code,  you used `map()`. By default `.x` was the matrix coming from the previous line. Let's say you use `map2()` in a similar way. I assume .x will be whatever the data from previous lines. .y will be something else. Can we denote the data with `.` and use .x and .y for other things? One more thing. If we have two arguments in an anonymous function, I assume we need to use `pmap()` given one of the argument would be data coming from previous lines?

Comment: If with `map`, it is `.x` and in `map2` there are two arguments, so it would be `.x` and `.y` while using `~`.  Otherwise, you can anonymous function like `function(x, y) x +y.  Let's say you are using arguments for `map2` as dataset and the column names of the dataset then `.x` will be the columns of the dataset and `.y` will the corresponding column names.  If it is a list of datasets, then `.x` will be the data.frame element of the list and .y the corresponding column names of the list of column names. .  If there are more number of arguments i.e. greater than 2, `pmap`

Comment: @akrun So for `map2`, .x will be a data set and .y will be column names. Is that right? One more thing. I am having hard time to find how to use `walk()` family. Have you used them?

Comment: It depends on the order.  If the first argument is data and second is names, yes. According to `?walk`, `walk() returns the input .x (invisibly). This makes it easy to use in pipe.`

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for that. I will play with `walk()`. Last several days were somehow the time to lean `Map()` and `map()`. Now I am getting used to these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `str_match`

```
library(stringr)
merge(stack(lapply(setNames(str_match_all(mydf$A, "(?=(...))"),
            mydf$A), `[`, , 2))[2:1], mydf, by.x = 'ind', by.y = 'A')
```

---

Or using similar idea with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
    mutate(Anew = str_match_all(A, "(?=(...))") %>% 
                map(~.x[,2])) %>%
    unnest   
#      A B Anew
#1 URBAN 1  URB
#2 URBAN 1  RBA
#3 URBAN 1  BAN
#4  PLAN 2  PLA
#5  PLAN 2  LAN
```